# ¿ Cómo hacer que se muestren toast en CalendarView en Fragment?

Tags: java, android

El problema es que tengo un Fragment y no funciona... :

He probado esto pero no funciona :

```
public class FragmentoPerfil extends Fragment {


    CalendarView calendar;
    public FragmentoPerfil() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        calendar = (CalendarView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                // display the selected date by using a toast
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmento_perfil, container, false);
    }


}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#dee4ee"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/espacio_norma_1"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="371dp"
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_weight="0.40" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/float_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Parte donde llamo a los Fragment en el MainActivity:

```
private void seleccionarItem (MenuItem itemDrawer)
{

        Fragment fragmentoGenerico = null;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        switch (itemDrawer.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.CALENDARIO:

                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentoPerfil();


                break;

            case R.id.PRIMERO:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentPrimero();
                break;

            case R.id.SEGUNDO:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentSegundo();
                break;

            case R.id.TERCERO:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentTercero();
                break;

            case R.id.CUARTO:
                fragmentoGenerico = new FragmentCuarto();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_share:
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "AndroidSolved");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "si que funciona");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
                break;
    }
```

Comment: No creo que se pueda considerar duplicado ya que esta pregunta hace referencia a un Fragment y la otra a un Activity.

Comment: Gracias Elena :)

Answer (score 0):

Asegura que en el layout que carga la `Activity` en realidad se encuentre el `CalendarView` ya que haces referencia a este en el layout de la `Activity` no en el `Fragment`:

```
 calendar = (CalendarView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
```

Para mostrar el Toast debe ser suficiente usar el contexto de la Activity:

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: El problema es que no está ahi el calendarView... pero no puedo ponerlo donde realmente está... :S tendré que indagar, gracias.

Comment: Por cierto Elena, me queda una duda gigante en mi proyecto, estas cosas las puedo intentar hacer pero... hay una que me supera y ya la planteé como pregunta también... tengo un arraylist que se muestra en un fragment pero necesito que al hacer click en uno se vaya a una activity pero sin "machacar" que ya la respondiste creo pero... no se me solucionó... :S

Comment: Entonces por eso no se puede mostrar el Toast. El calendarView lo puedes agregar en el layout del Fragment o del Activity.